# Xamarin form bind one Content page to another

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to bind(combining) 1 `ContentPage` .cs into another `ContentPage` xaml page. But I am missing something.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Class1" Title=""
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace;assembly:assembly">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="Select Refering Physician" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                  TextColor="Aqua" FontSize="20">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Handle_Handle" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" >
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <ContentView x:Name="overlay"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                 IsVisible="False"
                 BackgroundColor="#C0808080"
                 Padding="10, 0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" 
                   BackgroundColor="White" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   VerticalOptions="Start" 
                   Margin="0,20,0,0" >
                    <Label BackgroundColor="Black" FontSize="18" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Fill" Text="Search a user" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <local:ListviewPage>
                </local:ListviewPage>                  
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

cs class of above file

```
public partial class Class1 : ContentPage
    {
        ListviewPage objListviewPage;
        public Class1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            objListviewPage = new ListviewPage(); // I want to bind this page to my xaml file

        }
        void Handle_Handle(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SearchUser());
        }
        }
```

this class I am trying to bind

```
 public class ListviewPage : ContentPage
    {
        ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> ListItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> {
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 1"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 2"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 3"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 4"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 5"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 6"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 7"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 8"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 9"}
        };

        ListView ListView { get; set; }

        public ListviewPage()
        {
            ListView = new ListView();
            ListView.ItemsSource = ListItems;
            ListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
            ListView.ItemTapped += MenuListView_ItemTapped;

            var ListViewLayout = new StackLayout();
            ListViewLayout.Padding = new Thickness(10, 20);
            ListViewLayout.Children.Add(ListView);
            Content = ListViewLayout;
        }

        void MenuListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            (sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;

            var item = e.Item as ListViewModel;
            if (item.IsSelected)
                item.IsSelected = false;
            else
                item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

I dont want to navigate I want it to be render in same page

Comment: I don't think it is possible. And even if it is, I'm sure this is not the way, it would look like the way tabbed page do. Regardless, I guess a [control template](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating/) would be the better approach for you in this case, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do should be done with a separate view/control, which can be used in multiple pages, and not by trying to put pages inside of pages.

```
    public class ListViewControl : StackLayout
    {
        ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> ListItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ListViewModel> 
        {
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 1"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 2"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 3"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 4"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 5"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 6"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 7"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 8"},
            new ListViewModel{Text = "Item 9"}
        };

        ListView ListView { get; set; }

        public ListViewControl()
        {
            ListView = new ListView();
            ListView.ItemsSource = ListItems;
            ListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(CustomCell));
            ListView.ItemTapped += MenuListView_ItemTapped;

            //NOTE: this is where you would want to set any bindings,
            //either in code or by adding a xaml file to do it in there instead.

            Padding = new Thickness(10, 20);
            Children.Add(ListView);
        }

        void MenuListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            (sender as ListView).SelectedItem = null;

            var item = e.Item as ListViewModel;
            if (item.IsSelected)
                item.IsSelected = false;
            else
                item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

Then use that new class in your `RadShedulerDiagnosis` page, set a BindingContext on the page or your view and use your new control in xaml `<local:ListViewControl/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new content page and copy you code to that page. Its the easy way